# Android Spinner OnItemSelected doesn't called

Tags: android, kotlin, spinner

My Spinner OnItemSelected function never called.
When I click on spinner the list is shown. But when I click on some item in the list - nothing happened.

```
val adapter = ArrayAdapter(activity!!,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,nameOfClients)
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)
        mClientsSpinner.setAdapter(adapter)

        mClientsSpinner.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener{
            override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?, view: View?, position: Int, id: Long) {
                Toast.makeText(activity!!,nameOfClients[position],Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                selectedClient = nameOfClients[position]
            }

            override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) {

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
              spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(
                new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, 
              long id) {
                    Object item = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos);
                }

                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                }
            });
```

Comment: if you are not using custom spinner

Comment: It's still doesn't work. In Debug mode I saw that OnItemSelected listener executed only once - when activity opened.

Answer (score 0):

Following code worked for me where list is `ArrayList<String>`

```
val subjectAdapter = ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list)

//set drop down resource
subjectAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)

//set Adapter
spSelectSubject.adapter = subjectAdapter

//set listner

spSelectSubject.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
    override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>, view: View, position: Int, id: Long) {
        //your own method
    }

    override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>) {}
}
```